# To whom word "their" refers to?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1800241/synopsis)

> she has London banking connections, so their husbands will overhear
>   and beg her to let them invest with Irving.

To whom word "their" refers to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't give us the full sentence.

> The scheme is simple: Sydney tells **new acquaintances** that she has London banking connections, so **their** husbands will overhear and beg her to let them invest with Irving.

`their` refers to `new acquaintances`